# Membership Form - Remove Link under Membership Type

Tags: civimember

We have a link under one of our membership types on our membership sign up form and I am having trouble finding where the URL was created. It needs to be removed. Thank you!

Comment: maybe add a screenshot. also consider comparing with one of the demo site eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: also confirm what sort of form ie is it a Contribution Page, or a Drupal Webform, or an Afform, or something else

Comment: and welcome to this community :-)

Comment: Helllo thank you! It is our contribution page- you can see it on this page: https://integrativeonc.org/membership-benefits/join-renew, under "Membership" and then under the radio selection "International Members (MDs, practitioners, researchers)" there is text linked to a URL that we are trying to remove: "Please check list of countries".

Comment: on your contribution form (membership tab) settings, are you using a Price Set, or just the radio list of MembTypes that shows on that tab

Answer (score 0):

You may have some HTML in the Price Option of a Price Set that is in use on your Membership tab of the Contribution Page.

Go to /civicrm/admin/contribute?reset=1

Find relevant Contribution Page, click through to its Membership tab. Scroll down to find the name of the Price set. Then find this in the list of your Price Sets (at bottom of Contribution menu).

Then do a Preview, confirm the issue is showing there, find the right Price Option and remove as required.

Comment: Thank you! I did the preview of the price set selected on the contribution page and there are no HTMLs included, just selections with their corresponding prices. I wonder where it is coming from.

Comment: then perhaps it has been done in your theme, or a custom extension (or something else). you may find that just rebuilding that Price set and swopping it out might be the easiest fix, but  may affect some 'line item' reports as these will be different line items to what you were using initially